# Visual Studio text gets highlighed by default

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, highlighting

I must have pressed on the wrong button at some point, and now when i press my mouse a bunch of text gets highlighted ...how do i get rid of this? it's driving me nuts!

i use VS 2008

is there like a restore defaults button?????

Comment: Are you sure your shift key isn't stuck?

Comment: it appears that shift was indeed stuck, silly me. thanks guys

Comment: +1 because this made me laugh.

Comment: glad i could make someone laugh:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to Tools -> Import and Export Settings and then choose "Reset all settings".

Unless you actually changed your environment settings though, I doubt this will do it for you.  This sounds more like a key on your keyboard is stuck down.

Answer (score 1):

Do it from Tools --> Export and Import Settings...

Answer (score 0):

To reset IDE setting you could use menu `Tools->Import and Export Settings...|Choose Reset all settings`